# Force youTubePlayerFragment orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-youtube-api

I have a app which only allows portrait orientation.  I would like to force the youtube video to be set to landscape/horizontal orientation without going full-screen.  I have tried rotating the fragment that contains the video, which works to an extent (the container takes up the shape of landscape, but the video still plays in portrait mode).  I CANNOT set the activity to landscape because I need the rest of the view to keep it's portrait layout.

Here is my code for initializing the video:

```
    val youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance()
    val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit()
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("API-KEY",

            object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

                override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                                     youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, b: Boolean) {
                    // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                    youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(false)
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo("VID-ID")
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS)
                    youTubePlayer.play()
                    youtube_fragment.setRotation(90.toFloat())

                    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE)
                }

                override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                                     youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult) {
                    Log.e("vid", "error playing video")
                }
            }
    )
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Kind of.  I had to switch to a library that includes the functionality.  I believe it uses a Webview to show the video.

https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player

Answer (score 0):

Open video in new activity and force activity layout from manifest? When your video is lets say landsacape then is probaly everything in landscape.

Comment: I have to use fragments in order to keep my navigation working, and due to design constraints.  I tried forcing activity layout in fragment but it changes layout of EVERYTHING instead of just video.

Comment: I am afraid that you cant force just fragment to other orientation.